# Why did my Ubuntu installation fail?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I tried cleaning the partition which had Ubuntu installed (but was corrupted somehow and I wanted to reinstall) - I used gparted for it.  After deleting the partitions which contained ubuntu (I had another partition for windows), I tried re-installing ubuntu 12 - however, the installation failed complaining that there was no /dev/sda.  When I tried gparted again via live CD, its unable to find any devices on the computer.  I will run disk utility to gather more information - any other thoughts that could possibly help me get to the point where I can re-install ubuntu on my computer.  I noticed the option for reformatting on disk utility but I have not tried it yet.

Edit: I am assuming that I may have corrupted/deleted the NTFS partition somehow since I am unable to see any deviced on gparted now.  I am not entirely sure whether I should try format volume or drive via dis utility.  I will try running a bad blocks check as well.

thanks in advance

**Update**:
I can neither format drive nor volume using disk utility - it complains about "Daemon is inhibited".

**Update**:

When I tried running benchmark drive performance, I received the following error:

Error benchmarking: helper exited with exit code 1: Error reading 104857600 bytes at 104857600 from /dev/sda when guesstimating buffer size: Input/output error

**Update**:
GParted was already running and possibly holding onto a lock.  When I closed it, I was able to format the volume.

Update:
After formatting, I had issues with the ext4 filesystem.  I tried formatting it again - got the error (approximate) below - any thoughts?

mke2fs:
could not erase sector2 - short read
could not erase block 0 - short read
could not erase sector 0 - short read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reformat the volume and re-install Ubuntu after running checks for badblocks.  I will not be surprised if the hard drive gives up again very soon - I'll update the post if it does.  Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I think your hard drive is dying.

Comment: any suggestions on how to confirm that?

Comment: Googling the error you get, you can see it definitively means your drive is about to, or is already dead.